# express + ejs res.render called more than once

Tags: express, ejs

I am using express v4.6 and ejs v2.5.6
and i configured express like below:

```js
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const compression = require('compression')
const minifyHTML = require('express-minify-html')
const app = express()
const browse = require('./routes/browse')
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(compression())
...
app.get('/amp/browse*?', browse)
```

and browse is like below:

```js
module.exports = async (req, res) => {
const data = await fetchData(req)
res.render('../view/browse', data)
}
```

and i have used ejs for browse template view.
The problem is that res.render called more than once and a lot of extra api requests made by that.
Any idea? What is the problem?

Comment: The issue is not in the code you shared. Hayve you any other route matching, or any middleware ?

Comment: just bodyparser, minifyHtml and compression middlewares

Comment: please add a minimal example that repeats the issue. It must be full and complete.

Comment: what is the content of 'browse'  please ?

Comment: https://github.com/eh3rrera/node-amp-live-list
run this program and go to localhost://127.0.0.1:3000.
and add a log for render calls in server.js. and see the problem.